# Node.js and MySQL - How to prevent column names from being returned?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I am using the mysql module in Node to query a database.  Everything is working as expected with one exception.  There are times when I would prefer the result set to not contain the field names.  I suspect this is a JSONification thing but unsure how to disable it.

Here is a stripped down example:

```
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/getCountyByState/{state}',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            var state = request.params.state;
            var sql = 'select county_name from wyoming.county';

                if (typeof results !== 'undefined') {
                    reply(results);
                } else {
                    reply('Not found man!').code(404);
                }
           });
```

The resulting JSON object with the undesired field names:

```
[{"county_name":"Albany"},{"county_name":"Big Horn"},{"county_name":"Campbell"},{"county_name":"Carbon"},{"county_name":"Converse"},{"county_name":"Crook"},{"county_name":"Fremont"},{"county_name":"Goshen"},{"county_name":"Hot Springs"},{"county_name":"Johnson"},{"county_name":"Laramie"},{"county_name":"Lincoln"},{"county_name":"Natrona"},{"county_name":"Niobrara"},{"county_name":"Park"},{"county_name":"Platte"},{"county_name":"Sheridan"},{"county_name":"Sublette"},{"county_name":"Sweetwater"},{"county_name":"Teton"},{"county_name":"Uinta"},{"county_name":"Washakie"},{"county_name":"Weston"}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to get array of strings instead of array of object but simple way to convert it to what you want would be `var temp =[]; results.forEach(function (item) { temp.push(  item.county_name ) });`

Comment: Thanks @Molda .  I am using a crude map function similar to your forEach() to pull out the right hand side.  It works but it it isn't as elegant as I would like.